# Dwg to shp in GeoServer

Tags: qgis, openlayers-2, dwg

I am trying to load dwg in GeoServer and show it in OpenLayers, so I saved the dwg as dxf with AutoCAD. Then I used QGIS to save the dxf as shapefile.

But when I am trying to load the shapefile with GeoServer it can't calculate the bounds, and if I am trying to manually put the bounds it doesn't display the shapefile layer.

This is the way to display dwg? I did something wrong? There is other way?

Comment: can you veiw the shapefile in QGIS?

Comment: I read it with geoserver

Comment: but if it is a problem with the file then it won't work with qgis too, if it works with qgis then the problem is with how you're adding it to geoserver

Comment: I tried to open with qgis and I can't so the problem with the convert from dxf to shp, any other way to convert it?